# For 2nd order linear homogenous ODE, what is the effect of changing the value of the IC for $\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

Given a linear homogenous second-order ODE

$$f_2(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + f_1(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + f_0(x)y = 0$$

with initial conditions

$$y(x_0)=0$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}(x_0) = c$$

for some $x_0$, what is the effect of changing $c$?

The background for this is that I have been told that all solutions may be obtained from the solution for $c=1$. (In a context where multiplying the solution by a constant wouldn't make any difference, in case that is relevant.)

I can see that we would want to exclude $c=0$, because this would lead to the trivial solution $\forall x, y(x)=0$, but what does it mean to say that all solutions may be obtained with $y'(x_0)=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y$ be a solution of the differential equation 
$$f_2(x)\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+f_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+f_0(x)y=0,$$ satisfying the initial conditions $y(x_0)=0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}(x_0)=c\ne 0$.

Let $z=\frac{y}{c}$. Then $\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{1}{c}\frac{dy}{dx}$, and $\frac{dz^2}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{c}\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}$, and therefore $f_2(x)\frac{d^2 z}{dx^2}+f_1(x)\frac{dz}{dx} +f_0(x)z=0$, and $z(x_0)=0$, $\frac{dz}{dx}(x_0)=1$.

Conversely, if
$$f_2(x)\frac{d^2 z}{dx^2}+f_1(x)\frac{dz}{dx} +f_0(x)z=0,$$
 with $z(x_0)=0$ and $\frac{dz}{dx}(x_0)=1$, then $y=cz$ is a solution of your original equation, with $y(x_0)=0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}(x_0)=c$.

The "conversely" part says that all solutions with $c\ne 0$ can be obtained by scaling a solution which has $c=1$.

Comment: That is a clear and comprehensive answer, thankyou, and I hope to use your methodology to attempt similar problems in the future.

Answer (score -1):

A shift in initial conditions sometimes represents a certain translation of our solution. For instance, increasing $c$ may represent a horizontal shift to the left and vice-versa-

Comment: Are you sure about this in view of the [first answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/659014/77151) to this question, which categorically shows that changing $c$ corresponds to a scaling of the solution? It isn't obvious to me that there is any general rule which similarly relates initial conditions to a translation of the solution. Linearity acts in a special way w.r.t. multiplication because multiplication is repeated addition, and homogeneity means that the right hand side in invariant w.r.t. multiplication. I'm not sure you get any such powerful benefits with translation?